# Get data passed trought pushAsync

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on passing data from a `View` to a `Page`, to be more exact from `RecetasView` to `RecetaView`, showing the data in `RecetaView` works just fine using `{Binding}` in my `xaml` file, but i want to get the same data in C#.

The way I'm sharing the data:

`RecetasView.xaml.cs`

```
var selectedItem = e.Item as RecetasModel;
var recetaView = new RecetaView();
recetaView.bindingContext = selectedItem;
await Navigation.PushAsync(recetaView);
```

This is what I have tried to get the data:

`RecetaView.xaml.cs`

```
var receta = this.BindingContext;
```

But this crashes my app.

I can't really tell what's the error, because for some reason I can't debug the app in my device, I'm doing this on release.

Is there any other way to get the shared data in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property BindingContext is of the type object and hence when you get it from the property the `RecetasModel` data is actually of the type object and hence you need to cast it to the exact type before using it

```
var receta = this.BindingContext as RecetasModel;
if(receta != nulll)
{ //use receta }
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to do it inside `OnAppearing` method.

Answer (score 1):

you need to properly cast BindingContext

```
var receta = (RecetasModel)this.BindingContext;
```

Comment: App still crashing

Comment: then you need to do some basic debugging.  What exception is causing the crash?  Either use the debugger to figure it out or wrap the suspect code in a try/catch block.